# How to maximize damage to a tank in Battlefield 1?

Tags: battlefield-1

There are 3 different tanks in Battlefield 1 and several anti-tank weapons.
Tanks have damageable turrets (disables weapon) and threads (immobilizes tank). Armor can be damaged (not sure about effect).

Basicaly question is: What different parts of tank can I hit with anti-tank weapons and what damage will it make?

More specific:

- How much health each tank have?
- How side and angle of attack affect damage?
- How much damage turret takes before it is disabled?
- How much damage threads take before braking?

Related question: [How can I deal with Enemy Armor?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/284292/how-can-i-deal-with-enemy-armor), answer contains list of antitank weapons, but it does not specify details about tank health, armor or damage models.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deal with Enemy Armor?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/284292/how-can-i-deal-with-enemy-armor)

Comment: Linked questsion just lists antitank weapons, I ask how to best use them: attack angle, weak points.

Comment: Too many questions in one it seems, but I agree this is not a duplicate. Your going to want to split up this question into a few. Probably each one of your bullet points

Comment: Not only did I vote to leave this open, I'm upvoting because it's a good question. He's basically just asking what the hitboxes are on the tanks, combined with the angle of attack, if that's a factor. You could maybe split the questions about reparing off into another one.

Comment: I removed repair remarks. Now this question is about damaging tanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Battlefield/comments/515dzx/bf1tank_car_weak_spot/) on Reddit.

Tip 1: First of all, damage to vehicles (planes and ground alike) is localized which means that shooting one part of the tank will hurt that part. You may have noticed it says that you've damaged a track or more, which means that you can focus your damage to incapacitate or destroy the vehicles.

So when you are going head to head with a tank using AT grenades, hitting the actual tracks will disable it on the spot which is great if you want a quick getaway. However hitting the cannon will disable it stopping the driver/gunner from shooting you. Combine both these and you can take one out easily with a little teamwork.

Tip 2: If you are a scout and you're against the light armoured truck, your K Bullets will not only damage it but also penetrate and damage the occupants if you shoot the right place (Noticed this one earlier when I killed the gunner of one).

Tip 3: As long as you're near the main village you have the advantage; tank drivers and the gunners do not have the ability to aim high enough to kill players constantly switching buildings and running to roofs. High roofs mean easy target for AT grenades.

Tip 4: Cavalry have amazing AT potential so long as you dug and weave while your AT grenades recharge. And you provide a great distraction whilst others come to help you.
...............

I want to add that, if Battlefield 1 is based on true data about World War 1, every tank has one true weakness: it's their back.

Since the first tank created to our tank now, they where created so that their front part where "theoretically" indestructible so with all the "iron/steel plate" in front the back where not protected, so the tactics were to get around the enemies and destroy their back.

Also the tank tracks are weak, so if you aim for them and destroy them the tank cannot move anymore and so are strongly in danger. I hope I have responded correctly and enjoy the game.